# Como vincular um back em node para um front em react recharts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, visual-studio-code, crud

Preciso fazer um CRUD que é vinculada em um react recharts usando gráficos, procurei no youtube e não consegui achar de jeito nenhum como posso vincular o back em node com o front em react recharts com os dados em um gráfico, se alguém tiver uma dica de conteúdo ficarei muito agradecido.

Aqui está o CRUD que é uma tela de cadastro para as seleções da copa:

```js
const express = require('express');

const server = express();

server.use(express.json());

const times = ['Brasil', 'Alemanha', 'Dinamarca', 'Australia'];

// Retorna um time
server.get('/times/:index', (req,res) => {
    const { index } = req.params

    return res.json(times[index]);
});

// Retorna todos os times
server.get('/times', (req, res) => {
    return res.json(times);

});

// Criar um novo time
server.post('/times', (req,res) => {
    const { name } = req.body;
    times.push(name);

    return res.json(times);
}); 

// Atualizar um novo time
server.put('/times/:index', (req, res) => {
    const { index } = req.params;
    const { name } = req.body;

    times[index] = name;

    return res.json(times);
    
});

// Deletar um time
server.delete('/times/:index', (req,res) => {
    const { index } = req.params;

    times.splice(index, 1);
    return res.json({ message: "O time foi deletado" });

});


server.listen(3000);
```

Ela já está vinculada ao banco de dados, agora como posso colocar os dados no gráfico em React?

Answer (score -2):

Você vai precisar criar uma apliação em reactjs, para fazer as requisições no seu back pode utilizar o axios ou até mesmo o fetch.
O que vier de response do seu back você colocar no recharts, tem até exemplos de como fazer isso no próprio site eles.
A direção é essa, pelo que entendi da sua pergunta.